# If I lock when writing to a variable, do I also need to lock when reading, if the read is otherwise atomic?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, volatile

I have a class with code as follows

```
private readonly object m_lock = new object();

private IClient m_client
private object m_context;
```

When setting the client and context, I lock as follows

```
lock(m_lock)
{
    m_client = theClientFromSomewhere;
    m_context = contextObject;
}
```

My question is, if I only need to get the `m_client` by itself, is it safe to do this?

```
var localClient = m_client;

Debug.Assert(localClient != null);
localClient.DoStuff();
```

`m_client` is a reference type, so the read (when assigning to `localClient`) [is guaranteed to be atomic](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_12.5_Atomicity_of_variable_references), so this should work fine on a single CPU.

I could (also in theory) make the `m_client` variable `volatile`, and then this would be safe across multiple cpu's by preventing out-of-order reads by other CPU's, but the question is, does the lock-when-writing make it safe to read without being volatile?

Does locking when writing "flush" the CPU caches so that when they do a read it won't be out-of-order?

Comment: I've found by practice that I had to use both the lock and the volatile. Maybe it is just in my case(4 CPUs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lock` in C# (and, in general, the `Monitor` that it expands to in .NET) is a memory barrier - specifically, read barrier on acquire, write barrier on release. As for `volatile`, it adds a barrier for *every* read and write to the field. So, yes, you should be safe with `volatile` (assuming the rest of your code, which you didn't show, is doing everything correctly).

Comment: I'm aware that volatile would be safe across multiple CPU's, but is this safe without making it volatile (when I only want to read m_client and not the context)?

Comment: Hrm... On further thought it won't be safe, as I'd need a read barrier before the localClient = m_client... Can anyone confirm if this is correct or not?

Comment: Yes, this is precisely correct. If you don't have a read barrier there (either explicit, or `volatile`, or whatever else it may come from), you may read a stale value.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't have m_context, you wouldn't need the lock as both the read and the write are atomic. If, however, when you read m_client you also use m_context, then you have to lock both to prevent a situation where there's a context switch after updating m_client but before updating m_context.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, the performance is not great, but you could use a [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) to implement 1 writer and multiple readers.

Comment: If you're going to use that, use `ReadWriterLockSlim` rather than `ReadWriterLock`.